# How can I add an integer checking function to my simple math quiz

Tags: python, math

I'm having trouble understand how to add an integer checking function to my program, My program is a simple math quiz that uses numbers from 1-10 and the operators +,-, and division (Questions are randomly generated). The code works fine but in these parts is where it starts to go wrong for some reason

```
def intcheck(question, low, high):
valid = False
while not valid:
    error= "Whoops! Please enter a number between {} and {}".format(low, high)

    try:
        response = int(input("Enter an integer between {} and {}: ".format(low, high)))

        if low <= response <= high:
            return response
        else:
            print(error)
            print()

    except ValueError:
        print(error)

 # adds the question to questions dictionary
    questions.update({question:answer})
# Iterates through the questions in the dictionary and response respectively
for q in questions.keys():
    user_answer=input(q)
    if questions.get(q)==intcheck(user_answer, -100, 100):
        print("Correct!")
        score+=1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

I want the program to take whatever I put in and if its correct then print correct. If its incorrect and between -100 and 100 print incorrect. If it's not between -100 (min) and 100 (max) print Make sure your answer is an integer between -100 and 100 and if they don't enter an integer between -100 and 100 then it will loop until they do. If they do but the input doesn't = the answer print incorrect, but if they do and the answer is correct then print "Correct". But this is what happens

When I put a correct answer in
[image]

When I put a incorrect answer in
[image]

When I put something that isn't an integer between -100 and 100 in
[image]

When I put a correct answer in after putting something that wasn't between -100 and 100 in
[image]

When I put a incorrect answer in after putting something that wasn't between -100 and 100 in
[image]

I'm a beginner in python and could really use some help.